# Foil over cookie sheet over broiling pan?

Tags: temperature, cookware

My wife was cooking a recipe and was confused by instructions to put foil over a cookie sheet which should sit on a broiling pan. Foil is pretty standard in recipes, but why have the sheet on top of the broiling pan? She was cooking shrimp.

Comment: Was the broiling pan empty, or filled with water? If filled with water, this is a [bain-marie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bain-marie).

Comment: There were no instructions to put anything in the broiling pan. But thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that the recipe author was going for insulation from the heat of the oven's element/flames on the bottom.  This would give you more [cooking by convection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection_oven) - or baking without the browning on the bottom (conduction) where the food touched the thin pan.

Another way around this is insulated baking sheets - two layers with air in the middle.  On cookies, they take longer and reduce browning.  So this seems to me to be an approach to the insulated baking sheet, creating a workaround on the assumption that people have the other equipment at hand.